# The best way to securing React.js Route based on roles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I already implemented private routing in React.js with the help of library from react-aad-msal. When the user isn't authorized, it will show a landing page to ask the user to log in. The next step is we want to limit what the user can and cannot see. We have a table of users that contains Email and what role the user belongs to. We also have another table security roles detail, this table will return all the routes the user roles has. So we created an API that will return all the Routes the user has in the React app, and the returned data from API will filter the main `ListRouter` array in the React app. I already implemented all that but I just want to be certain that this is the best practice and doesn't have a flaw.
My code is looking like this:

```js
export const ListRouter = [
    {
        id: "1",
        title: "Menu1",
        linkto: "/Menu1",
        paths: '/Menu1',
        elements: <Menu1/>
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        title: "Menu2",
        linkto: "/Menu2",
        paths: '/Menu2',
        elements: <Menu2/>
    }, 
    {
        id: "3",
        title: "Menu3",
        linkto: "/Menu3",
        paths: '/Menu3',
        elements: <Menu3/>
    }
]
```

And then in App.js, we called an API to return all the available Routers:

```
// API Returns
["/menu1", "/menu2"]
```

After we got the data from the API then we filter the `ListRouter` based on the returned data in `useEffect`:

```js
const routerResult = await getFormListRouter().then(x => {
    var userModule = x.data;
    var module = ListRouter.filter((x) => {
        if (userModule.indexOf(x.linkto.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            return x;
        }
    });
    setRouters(module);
});
```

After that we use the state in the component to render all the Routers so when user don't have the permission to the page it will return no router matches.

```
<Routes>
    {routers.map((listmap) => (
    <Route
            path={listmap.paths}
            element={listmap.elements}
            key={listmap.id}
    />
    ))}
</Routes>
```

For now this already works, the user can't open the menu in the browser. From this implementation, is there anything should I be concerned of, or can I add something to make it more secure?

Comment: When something works just you want some extra pairs of eyes, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better pick.

Comment: Security on the client side is mostly pointless. You can set up showing/hiding content any way you want, as long as you never trust a client to be honest. The important part is to make sure that a client can only get the information it's allowed from the server.

Comment: you can create a private route wrapper

for eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-private-public-route

Comment: Hi, @super so by that mean I should more focus on the API side to limit the access? So the user can't access the data in this example in menu 3?  Because even with this the user still can tamper the data in the React.Js App?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang Yes. Focus on the API side. The user will always be able to tamper with data on the client side. Making sure they never have the data in the first place is the right option if you want real security.